# Group-by and aggregate a data frame with conditions of values from two column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

Say, I have following data frame,

```
df.head()
 col1   col2    col3    start   end gs
chr1    HAS GEN 11869   14409   DDX
chr1    HAS TRANS   11869   14409   Tp1 psg
chr1    HAS EX  11869   12227   Tp gn
chr1    HAS GEN  12613   12721   FXBZ
chr1    HAS EX  13221   14409   Tpghj
chr1    HAS EX  12010   12057   Tpghj
```

My columns of interest are `col3` and `gs`. I have two conditions,

- `col3` should be equal `EX`
- Use the value from column `gs`, if `col3` is equal to `GEN`

I always want the `gs` column with values of column `gs` if `col3 =="GEN"`

In the end, this is what I aim.

```
  df_converted.head()
    gs  chr      strt   end           ex_start           ex_end 
    DDX chr1    11869   14409   11869, 12613,13221  12227,12721,14409 
    FXBZ chr1   12613   12721   13221,12010         14409,12057
```

This is what I tried,

```
df.loc[((df.col3 == "EX") | (df.col3 == "GEN")), ['gs', 'start', 'end']].groupby(['gs']).agg(
    lambda x: ','.join([str(y) for y in x]))
```

Any suggestions/help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df1=df.loc[df['col3'].eq('GEN'),['gs','col1','start','end']].reset_index(drop=True)
df2=pd.DataFrame()
dex=df.loc[df['col3'].eq('EX'),['start','end']]
index=df[df['col3'].eq('GEN')].index.tolist()
v1=dex[dex.index>index[1]].T.values.tolist()
v2=dex[dex.index>index[0]].T.values.tolist()
df2['ex_start']=[v2[0],v1[0]]
df2['ex_end']=[v2[1],v1[1]]
print(pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1))


     gs  col1  start    end               ex_start                 ex_end
0   DDX  chr1  11869  14409  [11869, 13221, 12010]  [12227, 14409, 12057]
1  FXBZ  chr1  12613  12721         [13221, 12010]         [14409, 12057]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I am not sure why did you use the `df_converted` variable, it my desired output. From the question